# Kendo MVC Grid column type is not being set

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik-mvc, kendo-ui

I am migrating Telerik ASP.net MVC to Kendo ASP.net MVC. In Telerik MVC I bounded column with an object in array and specified object type in Bound call and all worked perfectly.

```
columns.Bound(field.EntityFieldType, field.EntityFieldName).Title(field.DisplayName).Template(g =>
{<%= g.GetValue(field.EntityFieldId)%>}).Width(field.Width);
.......
```

But using Kendo MemberType is ignored and remains null. Is there a different way how I can set a MemberType in Kendo? Or if Kendo uses only Data Schema for column data types then how I can update schema in runtime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that Telerik is deprecating usage of Type in Bound call and uses DataSource Schema Model instead. I solved my problem by clearing Model Schema before I bound any columns.

```
columns.Container.DataSource.Schema.Model.Fields.Clear();
```

And then after each bound column I added a new entry in Model Field List. As my field names contains dot (.) I need to put Field Name in Quotation marks, so that generate JSon is correct.

```
ModelFieldDescriptor modelField = new ModelFieldDescriptor();
modelField.Member = "\"" + field.EntityFieldName + "\"";
modelField.MemberType = field.EntityFieldType;
modelField.DefaultValue = null;
modelField.IsEditable = false;
columns.Container.DataSource.Schema.Model.Fields.Add(modelField);
```